# How to wrap a __construct() around mysqli_connect()?

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is mysqli_connect() as defined in the PHP manual:

```
mysqli_connect([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host")
               [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user")
               [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw")
               [, string $dbname = ""
               [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port")
               [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
```

Should I just do this for all the arguments?:

```
class MyClass {
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($host = '') {
        if($host == '') {
            $host = ini_get('mysqli.default_host');
        }

        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($host);
    }
}
```

If I do that for all the method arguments will it correctly wrap mysqli_connect()? Is there a more elegant may to do it?

**EDIT**:

After seeing Francios's answer and thinking about it a little more this seems like the best way to do it:

```
class MyClass {
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($host = '',
                                $username = '',
                                $passwd = '',
                                $dbname = '',
                                $port = 0,
                                $socket = '') {
        $this->conn = call_user_func_array('mysqli_connect', func_get_args());
    }
}
```

Would that wrap it correctly? The only thing that worries me is the $port because it is not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) assuming that your class expects the parameters to be the exact same as `mysqli_connect`.

```
class MyClass
{
  private $conn;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->conn = call_user_func_array('mysqli_connect', func_get_args());
  }
}
```

**With that said, the more elegant way is simply to extend the MySQLi class:**

```
class MyClass extends MySQLi
{
  // Custom functions that extend the functionality of MySQLi can go here.
}
```

Comment: @Francios I have chosen not to extend mysqli for various reasons. But your first snippet is good. I edited my question.

Comment: @Ryan - There's not need to specify any arguments. The `func_get_args()` that I'm passing to the `call_user_func_array` will pass all of the parameters that are passed to `__construct`. So, just `function __construct()` should work.

Comment: @Francios I understand what you're saying. Very elegant. Don't you think it would be confusing for other programmers though? Since the constructor doesn't show any parameters but in reality it takes many specific parameters.

Comment: @Ryan - If you're worried about that, you could do what you have up there but set all of the values to `null` (i.e. `$host = null`) so that if it's not set (i.e. `null`), the `mysqli_connect` function will replace them with the default values. An empty string is different than `null` and I don't know how the `mysqli_connect` would handle empty strings. Alternative, you could simply add a comment above the method for future programmer and let them know what parameters or accept or to see the `mysqli_connect` documentation for a list of parameters.

Comment: @Francios I was just reading the mysqli_connect manual and for host it says:`Passing the NULL value or the string "localhost" to this parameter, the local host is assumed`. So doesn't that imply that I must use `$host = ''` for the first constructor parameter? What should I use for the default $port value? Is there anyway I can see the actual mysqli implementation?

Comment: @Ryan - Which is why I'm suggesting you use `__construct($host = null, $username = null, $password = null, ...)` if you insist on including the parameters. By doing `__construct($host = '', $username = '', ...)` if the programmer doesn't specify a value, the empty string isn't necessarily the same as passing a null value and the `mysqli_connect` function might do something else. By passing `null`, you're letting `mysqli_connect` deal with the `null` values.

Comment: @Francios But if you send `$host = null` to `mysqli_connect()` it will assume localhost and it will not use the ini value. Which implies that `$host = ''` is correct.

Comment: @Ryan - I see what you mean. That makes complete sense now that I read the documentation!

Comment: @Ryan - Actually, I just tried that (just as above without any arguments) and used `ini_set('mysqli.default_host', 'example.org');` to change PHP's configuration and it worked great (it connected to example.org). Even if I add `$host = null` or `$host = ''` it works. Seems like all solutions work but just thought I'd share.

Comment: @Francios but does 'example.org' == 'localhost' in your case?

Comment: @Ryan - No. I used a remove server whose's hostname I didn't want to share so I used example.org).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many ways to skin a cat, and many ways to code a class.  You are in the right direction, though!

```
class MyClass {
  private $conn;
  private $host;  // defined as class variable to be used in connect()

  public function __construct($host = null) {
    if(isset($host)) {
       $this->host = $host;           
    }else{
       $this->host = ini_get('mysqli.default_host');        
    }

  }
  public function connect(){
      $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host);    
  }      

}    

// calling code ...
$db = new MyClass;
$db->connect();
```

Some would prefer having the connection method in a seperate method, the constructor has to do as little work as possible. This makes it much easier when you get into testing your classes.

Another detail more related to maintenance than to your actual question is the parameters, I would consider passing an optional array as arguments instead of having to list all the parameters individually in your constructor.

IE:

```
$dbSettings = array('host'     => 'localhost',
                    'username  => 'john',
                    'passwd'   => 'secret',
                    'database' => 'myDB'    
               );

    // class constructor now has one parameter only, with [type-hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) as an added bonus ..

        public function __construct(Array $dbSettings = null) {
           if(isset($dbSettings)){
             // assign values passed through the array
             $this->host = $dbSettings['host'];                                     
           }else{
             // assign values through ini settings ...
             $this->host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host");                  
           }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it's a bad one though because you don't have to do all that if else checking in the constructor. If you just pass the NULL or empty string values to mysqli_connect() then it should handle that stuff for you. See Francios's answer and my edit.

Comment: yes, possible but this was a not so great answer, it was mostly intended to demonstrate to op a different way of passing multiple parameters. Although mysql_connect does not require it, it seemed having $dbSettings to null was an easy way to enable calling this object with no $dbSettings.

Answer (score 0):

```
class connection {
    public  $input;
    public  $db_name = "dbname"; 
    public  $host = "localhost"; 
    public  $user       = "user"; 
    public  $ids        = "password"; 

    function __construct() {

        $this->dbc = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->ids, $this>db_name) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con)); 
    }


    public function view_connection() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column = '$this->input' ";
        $cart_result = @mysqli_query($this->dbc, $sql) or die("Couldn't get cart!");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cart_result)) {       
            $this->id = $row["id"];
            echo "This is the id - " .$this->id;
        }
    }
}
```